# Linq to XML reading Extrinsic node

Tags: linq-to-xml

Could anyone please show me how to read the extrinsic node below by using Linq to XML, please;

```
<Root>
<ItemDetail>
      <UnitPrice>
        <Money currency="NZ">32</Money>
      </UnitPrice>
      <Description xml:lang="en">abc description</Description>
      <UnitOfMeasure>CU</UnitOfMeasure>
      <Classification domain="N/A"/>
      <ManufacturerPartID>12345678</ManufacturerPartID>
      <Extrinsic name="StockCode">23333</Extrinsic>
      <Extrinsic name="Quantity">1</Extrinsic>
 </ItemDetail>
<ItemDetail>
      <UnitPrice>
        <Money currency="NZ">32</Money>
      </UnitPrice>
      <Description xml:lang="en">abc description</Description>
      <UnitOfMeasure>CU</UnitOfMeasure>
      <Classification domain="N/A"/>
      <ManufacturerPartID>12345678</ManufacturerPartID>
      <Extrinsic name="StockCode">23333</Extrinsic>
      <Extrinsic name="Quantity">1</Extrinsic>
 </ItemDetail>
<ItemDetail>
      <UnitPrice>
        <Money currency="NZ">32</Money>
      </UnitPrice>
      <Description xml:lang="en">abc description</Description>
      <UnitOfMeasure>CU</UnitOfMeasure>
      <Classification domain="N/A"/>
      <ManufacturerPartID>12345678</ManufacturerPartID>
      <Extrinsic name="StockCode">23333</Extrinsic>
      <Extrinsic name="Quantity">1</Extrinsic>
 </ItemDetail>
</Root>
```

Comment: The answer won't be a lot different to the last question you asked (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167541/linq-to-xml-reading-xml-document). try to adapt that.

Comment: @Martin, link you provided does not answer extrinsic nodes if you read carefully. I tried, is there a way to read name in linq to xml as I both name attribute are same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly do you want to achieve? Each `ItemDetail` element seems to have two `Extrinsic` child elements. Do you want to access both?

```
var data = from item in XElement.Load("file.xml").Elements("ItemDetail")
           select new {
              stockcode = (int)item.Elements("Extrinsic").First(e => e.Attribute("name").Value == "StockCode"),
              quantity = (int)item.Elements("Extrinsic").First(e => e.Attribute("name").Value == "Quantity")
           };
```

I am not sure stock code is an integer but of course you could take the string value instead (i.e. `(string)` instead of `(int)`).

Comment: Thank you @Martin. Exactly what I'm looking for, appreciate it.